# Change the default ErrorMessage of model validation attribute asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

How to avoid writing `[Required(ErrorMessage="My custom error message")]` every time and set the default `ErrorMessage` for whole project?

Comment: You could create a new public class with a static public property that contains `"My custom error message"`. However, you will need to set [Required(ErrorMessage=class.property")] everywhere instead, but it's an improvement over the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I have found the only way to use some sort of localization and resource files. You still need to write `[Required(ErrorMessage="<Resource Key Goes Here>")]`. But the advantage of just using constant messages like this `[Required(ErrorMessage=Class.Property)]` is that you can access attribute variables in resource file.

This is how I did it:

1. Create a folder in root named *Resources*
2. Create an empty class in *Resources* folder named *ValidationMessages.cs*
3. Create an empty file in *Resources* folder named *ValidationMessages.resx*
4. Edit the *.resx* file with VisualStudio editor
5. Example key,value pair for `[StringLength]` attribute: *"StringLength","Min length {2}, max length {1}"*
6. In model use attribute `[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "StringLength")]`
7. Add this code to *Startup.cs*

```
    using MyProject.Resources;
    ...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
                    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                        factory.Create(typeof(ValidationMessages));
                });
        ...
```

It's done.

Comment: This doesn't seems to work, I've even tried to create a custom StringLocalizer to pass as a  DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider but it never gets called!

Comment: For this to work  I have to specify the ErrorMessage key with: Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")

Answer (score 0):

> How to avoid writing [Required(ErrorMessage="My custom error
> message")] every time and set the default ErrorMessage for whole
> project?

You can create `custom attributes` to automatically generate error messages, but you inevitably need to add attributes to the corresponding fields to represent your constraints on the fields.

---

### Update

If you have multiple different validation requirements, then you can **merge them** into a custom attribute, and inherit the `ValidationAttribute` class.

The premise is that you need to *pass parameters to distinguish them*.

Here is a case：

```
public class CustomRequired : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public CustomRequired(string sepcialType)
        {
            this.SepcialType = sepcialType;
        }
        public string SepcialType { get; private set; }  

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            string errorType;
            if (value == null)
            {
                errorType = "required"; 
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SepcialType) && !IsValidEmail(value.ToString()))
            {
                errorType = "not valid";
            }
            else
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            ErrorMessage = $"{validationContext.DisplayName}  field is {errorType}.";
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
        bool IsValidEmail(string email)
        {
            try
            {
                var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
                return addr.Address == email;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Class:

```
 public class ThemTest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [CustomRequired("")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [CustomRequired("")]
        public string Theme { get; set; }
        [CustomRequired("Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Validate view:

```
@model ThemTest
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "TestAttr";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>TestAttr</h1>
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="field-validation-valid text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label asp-for="Theme"></label>
        <input asp-for="Theme" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Theme" class="field-validation-valid text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="field-validation-valid text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Good workaround but not all attributes can be inherited. For example, `EmailAddressAttribute` cannot be.

Comment: @VladislavKosovskikh, i have updated my reply, hope it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I do it.

In Startup.cs -> Configure(), set up your exception handler middleware:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

This redirects all exceptions to the home controller error method.
Now set up your viewmodel for Home/Error.

In ErrorViewModel.cs:

```
public class ErrorViewModel
{
    public string RequestId { get; set; }   
    public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);    
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public bool ShowExceptionMessage => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExceptionMessage);
}
```

In HomeController:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Error()
{
    ErrorViewModel errorViewModel = new ErrorViewModel();
    errorViewModel.RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;

    string message = "your message";
    errorViewModel.ExceptionMessage = message;
    _logger.LogError(message);
    return View(errorViewModel);
}
```

At this point your custom error message will be accessible in the model of your Error view page.

Comment: I don't use views. I actually have an api server. Also, I need a separate message for every property of model. Can't see how it may help.

Comment: An API server should still work the same way. Route the exception to an error controller with middleware, then in the error controller do a switch case on the property and return that property's custom message. Please visit this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1